# Does libgcrypt provide pkcs1 unpadding functionality?

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, gnupg

In the libgcrypt doco, it specifies that you can define an s-expression that allows for the data to be padded in PKCS#1 before being encrypted. Is there a another function or another expression I could build to unpad the data after it has been decrypted or is there some other work around to do this?

Thanks in advance!